# How to validate and parse more than 500MB XML file in perl

Tags: perl, large-files

Can any body help me out on how to validate and parse the 500MB file using perl.

I had try the libxml module but it only validates upto 400MB. and i also tried with `XML::SAX::ParserFactory`, which is giving me the Bus Error (core dumped).

I am very thankful on ur answers.

Comment: Without showing us the relevant parts of your code, there is no way to tell what exactly went wrong. Are you sure you are using your parsers in streaming mode? This should mitigate memory issues.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a more modern pull parser: [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aReader).

```
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => "file.xml")
           or die "cannot read file.xml\n";
while ($reader->read) {
    processNode($reader);
}

sub processNode {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Iam very thankful to you, it seems its working, now i have to check all the possibilities, how to capture the data :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) which is designed for this. It will be slower than XML::LibXML::Reader, but you may find it more convenient.